# JBoss EAP 7.0 throws many JMSRuntimeExceptions

Tags: session, transactions, jms, jboss7.x

I get many JMSRuntimeExceptions when I send a entity to a topic. The JMSContext is container managed by the JBoss EAP 7. Here is the code for sending the entity to topic and queue. I get many stacktraces and my log file exceeds the limit of 30 GB in a few hours:

```
@Inject
private JMSContext context;

@Resource(name = "java:/jms/topic/my.status.topic")
private Topic myStatusTopic;

@Resource(name = "java:/jms/queue/my.status.queue")
private Queue myStatusQueue;

public void handleEntities(@Nonnull final MyList myList)
  for (ListObject listElement: myList) {
    myEntity = new MyEntity();
    notifyQueues(myEntity);
  }
}

private void notifyQueues(@Nonnull final MyEntity myEntity ) {
  try {
    JMSProducer producer = context.createProducer();
    producer.send(myStatusTopic, myEntity );
    producer.send(myStatusQueue, myEntity );
    }
  catch(JMSRuntimeException e) {
    logger.warn("Error while sending: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

This is the entity:

```
@Entity
public class MyChangeEntity implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  private long id;
  private Instant created = Instant.now();
  private Integer customVersion;
  ...
}
```

And here is the exception:

```
javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: javax.jms.JMSRuntimeException: Could not create a session: IJ000460: Error checking for a transaction
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.handleInCallerTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:159) [wildfly-ejb3-7.0.1.GA-redhat-2.jar:7.0.1.GA-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInCallerTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:256) [wildfly-ejb3-7.0.1.GA-redhat-2.jar:7.0.1.GA-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:329) [wildfly-ejb3-7.0.1.GA-redhat-2.jar:7.0.1.GA-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:239) [wildfly-ejb3-7.0.1.GA-redhat-2.jar:7.0.1.GA-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41) [wildfly-ejb3-7.0.1.GA-redhat-2.jar:7.0.1.GA-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.WaitTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(WaitTimeInterceptor.java:43) [wildfly-ejb3-7.0.1.GA-redhat-2.jar:7.0.1.GA-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.jms.JMSRuntimeException: Could not create a session: IJ000460: Error checking for a transaction
        at org.wildfly.extension.messaging.activemq.deployment.JMSContextProducer$JMSContextWrapper.getDelegate(JMSContextProducer.java:234) [wildfly-messaging-activemq-7.0.1.GA-redhat-2.jar:7.0.1.GA-redhat-2]
        at org.wildfly.extension.messaging.activemq.deployment.JMSContextProducer$JMSContextWrapper.createProducer(JMSContextProducer.java:267) [wildfly-messaging-activemq-7.0.1.GA-redhat-2.jar:7.0.1.GA-redhat-2]
```

The consumer (MDB) tries to merge the received entiy. But the merge fails and on rollback I receive a RollBackException:

```
javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: javax.jms.JMSRuntimeException: Could not create a session: IJ000460: Error checking for a transaction
```

It seems that JBoss EAP 7 has a problem with session or with checking for a transaction because the error occurs very often. Could anybody help me? If you need more information please ask me.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is no active transaction in the context of the method.

How is the class configuration ({{ejb-jar.xml}}, used annotations)? Is it a cdi bean or ejb?

Is there some more {{Caused by:}} clauses in the log for the particular exception?

Or the transaction was already terminated for some reason and the context is gone - kind of long running transaction is terminated because of timeout - check the timeout for transactions settings, your code explicitely already rolled-back the transaction (possibly RuntimeException was thrown).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply.

The problem was not in JMS. It has been a database transaction which was broken. So the exception in the the database transaction was responsible for the JMSRuntimeException. It was not a real JMS problem.